# Apply drop caps to each word in a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, capitalization

I'd like to recreate the menu effect seen at http://www.thedecoratorsource.co.uk using CSS fonts and drop caps.

I know that I can use

```
p.introduction:first-letter {
font-size : 300%;
}
```

which will give me the first word with a larger first characerer but I want to apply it to each word. I'm guessing there isn't a way to do this with CSS(3). Would my best bet with javascript? I've already got Moo on the page so this would be my preferred method.

I don't want to add extra HTML to my links to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: There is `text-transform: capitalize` but that doesn't quite get you there.

Comment: are you attempting to capitalize all the letters ?

Comment: @kjy112 Nope, capitalize will only capitalize the first letter of each word. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#caps-prop

Comment: i was reffering to using javascript instead of css.

Comment: @hemlock lol no biggie, but NOW i learn there's a capitalize now in css

Comment: What I'm after is actually font-variant:small-caps; but there is an added complication that I'm using @font-face and unless the font has small-caps, it reverts to default (or so I assume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't drop caps (that's when you have a big capital letter at the start of a paragraph that takes three or four lines). This is Small Caps.

Easiest way is to find a small caps font, and capitalise every word. Sadly the only font I can find on google web font api that has small caps might not have the right character:

http://code.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Walter+Turncoat&subset=latin

Comment: Close but the font-variant: small-caps does the job, but the font needs to be suitable. Closest answer so far though. I'll see if anyone can recommend a font.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this in your menu:

```
li {text-transform: uppercase;}
li:first-letter { font-size:150%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) would help with that, although it's for jQuery, not Moo.

Answer (score 0):

you can use toUpperCase(); javascript function to make all the letters capitalize. Example:

```
var str="This is my 1st new tutorial 123";
var a1 = str.toUpperCase();
document.write(a1);
```

so, in your case i would grab all the elements' contents that you wish to capitalize and apply the toUpperCase() function to the letters.

Mootools Version:
HTML:

```
<ul id='mylist'>
    <li><a href='#'>test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>test 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>test 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Mootools JS:

```
$$('#mylist li').each(function(el) {
    console.log(el.getElement('a').innerHTML.toUpperCase());
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JQWpf/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on these other answers, I'm not sure I understand the question. BUT, based on my understanding this must be done with JS if you want that exact effect. Not much moo to it though.

This will add a span around the first letter of each word and apply a class to it. You can do whatever you want to the first letters in your css after that.

```
  $$('p.introduction').each(function(el) {
    var text = el.textContent || el.innerText;
    el.innerHTML = text.replace(/\b(\w)([^\b]*?)/g, function(match, first, remainder) {
      return ['<span class="first-letter">', first, '</span>', remainder].join('');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> font-variant: small-caps;

It works in all browsers.

Comment: Only if the font you're embedding has small-caps in the actual font file.